# Embarcadero "Conditional defines" settings - whats the difference?

Tags: compiler-construction, c++builder-xe2

What's the difference between these two settings in Project Options window?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first contains global conitionals.  The second inherits the global conditionals and can add additional conditionals if desired.  It is just another way of sharing common conditionals across multiple build configurations.